# Pub/Sub multiple Subscribers to One Subscription message routing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a scenario where there are 4 kubernetes pods running the same pubsub subscriber code which sends pullingStreamRequest to a single subscription.
I am using the Go pubsub client library - https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub@v1.25.1#section-readme

I understood from https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber

```
Pull subscription
Multiple subscribers can make pull calls to the same "shared" subscription.
Each subscriber receives a subset of messages.
```

My follow-up question is that if maxOutStandingMessages is set as 10 for each pullingStreamRequest from the 4 subscribers, how will GCP Pub/sub server load balance between the subscribers?

**Extra questions:**
Will the server ensure that 10 are sent to one of the subscriber first everytime before moving onto the next?

Will the server treat each subscriber as having 10 maxOutstandingMessages limit for each? Or the limit 10 is shared among the 4 subscribers.

I tried looking up the GCP documentation and code but unfortunately could not find an answer to this. Will appreciate any help in clarification thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as a subscriber starts up and connects to Pub/Sub, it is a candidate to receive messages. The service is not going to wait until one subscriber has 10 outstanding messages before sending messages to the next subscriber.  Messages will be send across these different subscribers as they are available. There isn't going to be a discernible pattern as it depends greatly on the routing of subscribe requests across the service. The only exception is that if you use ordering keys, then messages for the same ordering key will be delivered to the same subscriber on a best-effort basis. However, given that it is on a best-effort basis, the keys may occasionally shift among subscribers (especially if existing subscribers disconnect or new subscribers connect).

The max outstanding messages limit is per subscriber, not across all subscribers, so if you have 4 subscribers and each has the max outstanding messages set to 10, then you can have up to 40 messages outstanding.

Comment: Thank you Kamal Aboul-Hosn for the response!! Can I ask another question, with regards to what was mentioned here in flow control: https://medium.com/google-cloud/things-i-wish-i-knew-about-google-cloud-pub-sub-part-2-b037f1f08318 

"streaming pull can’t split up messages from a single publish batch"

do you know if it means that if a publisher batch publishes 500 messages, all that will go to one subscriber at one-go? but the subscriber will only process up to maxOutstandingMessages and expire the rest for sure?

Comment: That blog post is actually out of date. This has not been a limitation for about six months now.

Comment: I have a question, for one subscriber, if numGoRoutine == 2, and subscriber is on synchronous pull or streamingPull, does it mean the subscriber will make two requests parallel to pub/sub server? How will the maxOutstandingMessages affect this? Will GCP pub/sub server still ensure across these pull requests, there can only be up to maxOutstandingMessages delivered to the pulling client?